# How to show custom message while submitting workflow comment window?

Tags: sitecore-client, workflow

I have created a custom comment template with two field - Comments and Author Name. I marked both the fields validation as Required.
I applied this custom comment template to my workflow and this workflow is applied to template.

So when I submitting his workflow items, my custom window is displaying. If I am not entering any values in this custom comment window fields, Sitecore give me message box as "Some of the fields in this item contain critical errors. Are you sure you want to save this item?" as below

[image]

My question is that how can I change this message to some custom message?

Comment: How do you even make a comment there required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a dictionary item in `core` database. So go to the `core`, open `Content Editor`. Search for this item: `/sitecore/system/Dictionary/S/Some of the fields in this item contain critical errors   Are you sure you want to save this item`. Here you can set the `Phrase` to your language.

Answer (score -3):

Its coming from the processor . you can decompile the Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Validators processor and you can see the message in code.

Comment: Kindly share more details with your answer. Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment.